# Rails: how to filter render partial results based on an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a very basic question, however, I can't find a simple answer in any of the documentation.

Use Case:

- Render only Microposts with type_micro = "business"
- Can I pass this criteria in index.html.erb where the partial is called to make it a simple implementation?

**Current code:**

1) `microposts/index.html.erb`

```
<%= render @microposts %>
{{how can I pass type_micro = "business" right here?}}
```

2) `microposts table`

```
 id         | integer                     | not null default 
 title      | text                        |
 body       | text                        |
 user_id    | integer                     |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 type_micro | character varying
```

3) `_micropost.html.erb`

```
<span>
     <p class="title-post"><%= link_to micropost.title, micropost_path) %> </p> </span>
```

4) `Micropost Controller`

```
 def index

    @microposts = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page])
     @micropost = @micropost.find(params[:type_micro])
  end

  def show
      @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
      @micropost = @micropost.find(params[:type_micro])

       respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @micropost }
        end
  end
```

**UPDATE:** I want to pass type_micro so I can separate "business", "management", "social" into three sections in my view. I looked up solutions via Google as there is no documentation on something this simple. Nothing worked, tried what has been recommended here as well. Here is where the code is now:

Controller:
def index

```
@microposts = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page]
```

end

def show
      @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])

Cant add  @micropost = @micropost.find(params[:type_micro]) as I get error, Find is not define. Not sure why.

Index.html.erb

The above does not show microposts that are all "business". It filters nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to pass `type_micro = "business"` into the partial. From your controllers code, looks like you are already filtering microports of type 'businesses' based on the `params[:type_micro]`?

Nevertheless, views, including partials have access to the `params`. So you directly call `params[:type_micro]` in the partial. Or you could also set the `@type_micro` = params[:type_micro]`in your controller's action and acceess`@type_micro` in the partial.

In the last resort, if you indeed need to pass "business" as `type_micro` into your partial for some other reason, you could try `<%= render @microposts, locals: { type_micro: "business" } %>` and you will have `type_micro` accessible as local variable in your partial with its value as "business".

Refer to [PartialRenderer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<%= render @microposts, type_micro: "business" %>
```

then on your partial, you can call for the `type_micro` in your partial html